# Xlsxwriter: get data which was written?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I want to simulate autofit in xlsxwriter. I can do that easily when I have a 2D list of data to be written to a sheet, because then I can use Len() in every string in my 2d list and find the max() length column-wise.

But when I have a sheet which gets written from many different functions without having all the data in one 2d list, I'm calling many times sheet.write.

Now I'm wondering how to retrieve the data from the sheet so that I can apply the same procedure again. I searched what I was expecting to fetch the data, but there's nothing like

Sheet.data
Sheet.columns

Or similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any methods in XlsxWriter to retrieve data once it has been written.

In order to do what you want you will have to track the maximum string lengths in your various functions that write data.

Comment: OK Thanks, i thought maybe internally you keep track of everything the user writes as a 2d list of strings. But than I'll keep track myself, thanks

Comment: One approach might be to override the `write_string()` method and run the overridden method first and if it returns successfully store the string length in a column number indexed dict in the worksheet. This would also take care of cases such as `write_url()` which calls `write_string()` internally.